# jQuery append() to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Trying to learn jQuery yet having trouble solving this problem. This is what I have so far:

```
var todoListItems = [
   {"title" : "Walk the dog"},
   {"title" : "Clean the car"},
   {"title" : "Do the laundry"}
  ]

// Append each to do list item in the 
// array to the un ordered list with 
// the id of "todo-list".
// Use jQuery.

var addTodos = function() {
  $('#todo-list.ul').append(todoListItems);
}

$(addTodos)
```

Do I need to use the .each() method to run through the array? Can't figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `.each()` to append each item, and you need to append something other than those plain objects; what do you expect that to do? And `$(addTodos)` should be `addTodos()`.

Comment: While `append` accepts an array, it must be an array of elements, not some simple objects.

Comment: I expected `append` to add the objects from the array which sounds like I am wrong in understanding how to solve this problem.  So should I be appending the key `title` rather than the variable ?

Comment: @Pointy probably unintended by OP but `$(addTodos)` works fine as a `document.ready` call

Comment: @charlietfl oh yes duhh, of course.  Never mind that part of my comment OP.

Comment: @A.White The jQuery `.append()` function is for appending either HTML in text form, a DOM element reference, or another jQuery object to an existing part of the DOM. You're code looks like it's trying to pass in those plain JavaScript objects. What do you expect adding an object to the DOM to do? I mean, what sort of HTML elements are you expecting those objects to become?

Comment: @pointy I am expecting the list in the array to become <ul> HTML elements. Right now this: 
`<ul id="todo-list">
  </ul>`
is empty I am trying to write a jQuery func to add the items in the array to the <ul> . So it appears as a complete list when I run the script.

Comment: OK well that's not going to happen by magic. You have to explicitly put together the `<li>` elements and accumulate them into a `<ul>` element, and then add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
var todoListItems = [
   {"title" : "Walk the dog"},
   {"title" : "Clean the car"},
   {"title" : "Do the laundry"}
  ]

$.each(todoListItems, function( index, value ) {
  $('#todo-list.ul').append(value["title"]);
});
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP explained he/she desires in a comment. The OP wants a `<ul>` with each item in an `<li>`. Your code will append the text as simple text nodes.

Comment: @pointy Correct, I need each item in the array to appear as a <li> . When I add <li> to my code:
  `$('#todo-list li').append(value.title);` 
The items appear as such:  

     Walk the dogClean the carDo the laundry
     Walk the dogClean the carDo the laundry
     Walk the dogClean the carDo the laundry    

How do I separate each item for each <li>?

Comment: Make some changes in above code `$('#todo-list.ul').append("<li>" + value["title"] + "</li>");`